# Invoking a function from a shared library does not work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I wrote a groovy code that disables a job if it falls more than 3 times. When i add the code directly to the Jenkinsfile before the main pipeline, it works as expected. I decided to move the code to shared libs, added lib to jenkinsfile, call it, but nothing happens. Can you tell me what I can to do?

It works as expected:

```
passedBuilds = []
def call(build) {
    if(build != null && build.result != 'SUCCESS') {
        call(build.getPreviousBuild());
        passedBuilds.add(build);
    }
 }
 call(currentBuild.getPreviousBuild());
if (passedBuilds.size() > 3) {
  println "Oh no!"
  manager.build.project.disabled = true
} else {
  println "Ok!"
}

pipeline {}
```

It does not work

```
@Library('shared-libraries@main')_

disableJobInUnstableCases()

pipeline {}
```

Comment: What is the organization of your shared library for both code and files?

Comment: can you share you `disableJobInUnstableCases()` function from shared libraries?

Comment: @YuriG. It already shared in the first code block, before pipeline section

Comment: @ЮрійПанейко The shared code is a code from Jenkinsfile. Can you share the definition from the shared library? Is it a custom step under `vars` folder? What's the exact content of this file? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the working code there is:

```
def iterate(build) {
  passedBuilds = []
  if (build != null && build.result != 'SUCCESS') {
    iterate(build.getPreviousBuild())
    passedBuilds.add(build)
  }
}

def checkForOverLimit() {
  if (passedBuilds.size() > 5) {
    println 'Oh no!'
    manager.build.project.disabled = true
  } else {
    println 'Ok!'
  }
}

def call() {
  iterate(currentBuild.getPreviousBuild())
  checkForOverLimit()
}
```

Then just call the library from pipeline